# How to iterate multiple data frames in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to remove rows that have missing values from 12 data frames.
I could use na.omit for each of them but that's to much syntax.

I've tried to do it in multiple ways:

**Like this:**

```
df <- list(df1,df2,df3,df4,df5,df6,df7,df8,df9,df10,df11,df12)

for (i in 1:length(df)){
  df[i] <- na.omit(df[i])
}
```

**And like this:**

```
for (df in list(df1,df2,df3,df4,df5,df6,df7,df8,df9,df10,df11,df12)){
  df <- na.omit(df)
}
```

None of this methods worked :)

Could someone please let me know what is missing here to properly iterate multiple data frames?

Comment: Better to ask this at stack overflow here it will just be closed.

Comment: OP, please note that SO requires minimal reproducible examples, which this lacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
df1 <- df2 <- data.frame(a=c(NA, 1), b=1:2)
dfs <- list(df1, df2)
dfs[] <- lapply(dfs, na.omit)
```

As for why they don't work:

```r
dfs <- list(df1, df2)
for (i in 1:length(dfs)){
  dfs[i] <- na.omit(dfs[i])
}
```

Here you're using single square bracket subsetting, which returns a list, then calling `na.omit` on a list of length 1, where element 1 is the first df. Since the df is not `NA`, it's returned as-is. ie,

```r
dfs[1]
#[[1]]
#   a b
#1 NA 1
#2  1 2
```

And...

```r
for (df in list(df1, df2)) {
  df <- na.omit(df)
}
```

Here you're iterating over the dfs but storing the result of each in `df`. R doesn't really handle references (everything is copied on write) so `df` stores the result of `na.omit(df1)` after the first iteration and the result of `na.omit(df2)` when the loop ends.